# How to show foreign characters using JSTL/EL?

Tags: jsp, character-encoding, jstl

I am printing foreign data using JSTL `<c:out>` tag. The `${data}` contains foreign characters. 
But it's not showing properly. Is there any parser to show foreign characters? Or any other way?

Comment: you should accept answers on your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in top of your JSPs.

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

It will set the response encoding and instruct the webbrowser by the proper response headers to interpret it as such.

You only need to ensure that "foreign data" is been encoded in UTF-8. So if the source is a SQL database, ensure that the DB and table use UTF-8. Or if the source is a text file, ensure that it's been saved and read as UTF-8.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Hi @BalusC! I tried your solution. But it doesn't work. Any alternative solution?

Comment: There's no alternative solution. Your problem is caused elsewhere and therefore needs a different solution.